# Error is occuring during implementation of MGTwitterengine

Tags: iphone, mgtwitterengine

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/MYcomputer002/Documents/MGTwitterEngineTest/yajl/build/yajl-1.0.7/lib'
ld: framework not found Cocoa
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

I am implementing MGTwitterEngine in my project. After large modification and removing an error I stuck with the above error. What about this exact error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MGTwitterEngine references but doesn't contain [yajl](https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc). You have to add it yourself. You can download and copy the files manually or add it as a framework following the instructions at the yajl page.

If you dig around in the MGTwitterEngine you'll see the yajl files in red, that means they are missing. You'll find the same problem with OAuthConsumer and TouchJSON.

Comment: @jano, Thanks for reply. I downloaded files from the link and i added it in project directory well. And I also dragged in my Xoce3 project. This is added successfully. But when I am trying to compile it I am seeing an error No such file or directory : Yajl/yajl_common.h". What i should to do ? I was downloaded file from the above link.

Comment: Try this: make a copy of the whole https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc/tree/master/yajl-1.0.11 folder inside the MGTwitterEngine project (including subfolders). Then delete the yajl folder from the MG project and add the yajl-1.0.11 folder.

Comment: @Jano, My all errors is now gone but now I am getting above mentioned error. "ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mycomputer002/Documents/MGTwitterEngineTest/yajl/build/yajl-1.0.7/lib'
ld: framework not found Cocoa
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1 "

Comment: Go to Build Settings in the target MGTwitterEngine, type yajl, you'll see the nodes Library Search Paths, Header Search Paths. Double click the value on each of them and delete the entries referencing yajl-07. Since you just added the source files for yajl, you don't need it there. I guess it was intended to link to a parallel yajl project.

Comment: @Jano. above error is removed now. But now I am getting error in Libxml/xmlreader No such filr or directry in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.h file . Please explain me about this error.

Comment: Go to Build Settings > Header Search Paths and add: `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2`